# How do I make my Mac use .bash_profile to add extra paths after I statically set $PATH?

Tags: macos, bash, path

I, like an idiot, decided to `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin/`.

After some googling I was informed that one should use a `.bash_profile` file in the root directory of your user which you can use to append paths to the initial `$PATH` . However the `.bash_profile` file did not exist prior to me creating one so I'm unsure how to prompt my Mac to actually use this file as part of it's `PATH` configuration. Every site I've visited simply tells you to make edits to said file but does not explain how to get the OS to use it.

How do I get my Mac to read from `.bash_profile` to add custom paths?

Comment: This file is normally in your home folder and it's read automatically; try `cat ~/.bash_profile` to see if the file exists: it is invisible in finder. Or, alternatively, run `ls -lah` in your home folder to see if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

The bash shell actually defaults to look for `~/.bash_profile` even though it may not initially exist.

After creating this file in the root directory of your user, just enter `source ~/.bash_profile` . This forces the bash shell to read immediately from the file and will run it's contents straight away.

As long as you have a line that looks like `export PATH=<directories>` in the file, your `PATH` will be set by this every time.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819142/2528868) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cd ~
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:(insert other path here)"' > .bash_profile
```

or

```
cd ~
touch .bash_profile
nano .bash_profile
```

This file is read automatically.